# How to use jQuery to retrive all the selected and non selected elements of a multiselect in the same order as it is in multiselect box

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use jQuery to retrieve all the selected and non selected elements of a multiselect in the same order as it is in multiselect box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#your_selectbox_id').find('option').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array= [];   $('#multiple :selected').each(function(i,selected){array[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```

Here is the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector//)

Comment: I want all the available options with the same order

Comment: let it be selected or non selected, all the options should come one by one from top to bottom.

Comment: you will get selected all values in array

Comment: no no no prassd bro... I don't want all selected values only..I want all the options available...whether it is selected or not doesn't matter.

Comment: All the available options should come one by one from top to bottom irrespective of selected or non selected.

Comment: $('#your_selectbox_id').find('option').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
});

Comment: This is the answer...!!